# spring boot jms initialcontext

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jms, spring-jms

I'm looking to configure a Spring boot application to do a JNDI lookup (configure initialContext) of the connection. This is running as a standalone Spring boot application (not on an application server). I have the following which works fine, although I provide all the configuration values myself (not setting timeouts/etc here, but would normally be):

```
@Bean
public ConnectionFactory tibJmsConnectionFactory() throws JMSException {
    TibjmsConnectionFactory myFac = new TibjmsConnectionFactory();
    myFac.setServerUrl("tcp://xxxxx:7222");
    myFac.setUserName("xxxxxxx");
    myFac.setUserPassword("xxxxxx");
    return myFac;
}

@Bean
public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> myFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                                                DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
    return factory;
}
```

When running on an application server, you can set up a JNDI context URL to pull configuration values (timeouts/etc) from an external connection (in our case, the source JMS server) by specifying an "Initial Context Factory" on the JNDI connection. How I can do the equivalent from a Spring boot application not running on an application server?

Answer (score 0):

Your tibJmsConnectionFactory() isn't returning connection factory from server. You're just instantiating it with some properties. You've to do context lookup.

```
    Context ctx = new InitialContext(env);      

    TibjmsConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (TibjmsConnectionFactory) ctx.lookup("factoryName");
```